# c++ - struct and class padding

Tags: c++, class, struct, alignment

I always pad my structs in C to get the maximum performance (good memory alignment).

```
// on a x86_64 
struct A {

 int64_t z;
 int32_t x;
 int16_t y;
 // we don't care the uint8_t position, as they are 1 byte wide.
 uint8_t s[8];
 uint8_t t[4];

}
```

But if I decide to go the c++ route, creating an object for another purpose, I need a class:

```
class B {

   B(){}
  ~B(){}

 public:
   int64_t a;
   int8_t  b;

 private:
   int32_t c;

//methods...
}
```

Then, c is not aligned anymore.

Is there a way to avoid doing that (multiple labels):

```
class B {

  B(){}
  ~B(){}

 public:
   int64_t a;

 private:
   int32_t c;

 public:
   int8_t  b;

}
```

(on some cpus, alignment matters).
 Thanks

Comment: I doubt the class is not aligned

Comment: It is not about the class, but the variables inside it. I could not find anything saying that it is automatically aligned and correctly organized. i don't want to lose too many bytes.

Comment: I doubt the class members are not aligned

Comment: Isn't this something you shouldn't even think about doing to your code until you exhaust all other optimizations?  First code good readable code and then figure out where you need to trim some fat.

Comment: if you look at the memory layout (get addresses of the class and the members) you will see they all are aligned properly in either case. As well as the class is

Comment: @NathanOliver: how do you know we didn't put all the efforts already ? I code in c and assembly. I am new to C++ but not c/assembly coding :) We try the language.

Comment: @DieterLücking: it is not only alignment.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883655/access-specifier-in-c/4883764#4883764

Comment: @NathanOliver: nice addition. +1

Comment: Are you sure, do you get maximum performance on padding? @Kroma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Put all the state in a struct, aligned and padded as you wish. Preferably no member functions on the struct, keep it trivial. The class holds a private instance of this struct. Class member functions act on this state directly.

That should suffice. Plus you get a clear separation between state and functions which is always nice. Tends to be used with set/get functions in the class, unless you're especially attached to using inconsistent syntax for function calls and state access.

Alignas may also be of interest.

Comment: that is an interesting idea Jon

Comment: you could do the same directly in the class. make all member private in the appropriate order and access them with functions. outcome is the same and you do not have to dereference an additional level (with no semantic) all the time.

Answer (score 0):

your effort is complete waste of time. the compiler does the alignment of himself correct (if you not explicitly tell him not to do so).
It inserts bytes between members. and it inserts enough bytes at the end of the structure in a way that that its overall size is a multiple of the structures alignment rule.

Your effort is also contra productive. that if compiling for another architecture with other alignment rules? then the compiler inserts padding bytes to your padding bytes.

Explicit alignments and packed structs only matter if data should be exchanged beyond the scope of the compiler or architecture.

Comment: Wrong. You don't get that sometimes we need to have the right alignment and the minimum size for a struct/class.

Comment: You're right about the compiler aligning stuff properly for performance, which is what OP asked about, but someone else might still want to do that task to save memory lost to padding

Comment: Padding occasionally matters a lot - putting atomic variables on different cache lines to prevent false sharing is the main example that comes to mind. It does tend to be platform specific unfortunately.

Comment: @Kroma if you want minimum size then you have to change the order of your members. manual padding can not help you in any way to save memory.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: yes, i know that ! Thanks